# I want to pass flag name to other activity and to show each web view if equal flag

Tags: java, android, webview, flags

I have two main activities.In login activity ,if I clicked login button to pass flag to main activity.In main activity,if equal flag go to login page of web view .if not so,stay home page.When I created it,pass flag variable is ok but if I clicked login button ,it always go to home page.Please help me kindly.I am learning android as a beginner.

**piece of code of MainActivity.java**

```
 String flag = getIntent().getStringExtra("flag");
    Log.d("FlagCheck", "this flag is  (" + flag + ")");

    if (flag=="add"){
        webview.loadUrl(login_address);
        Log.d("FlagCheck", "this flag is  login_address");

    }else{

        webview.loadUrl(home_address);
        Log.d("FlagCheck", "this flag is  home_address");
    }
```

**piece of code of LoginActivity.java**

```
mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBoxRememberMe.isChecked());
            if (checkBoxRememberMe.isChecked())
                savePreferences("storedName", mEmailView.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());


          /*  int requestCode = 1001;
            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
            startActivityForResult( intent, requestCode );
            intent.putExtra( "key", "result_val" );


            setResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, intent );*/


            finish();
           // startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));


           // finish();
           Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("flag", "add");
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Use `str.equals("add")` for string equality checks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `str.equals("add")` or `str.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

As == doesn't checks whether both strings are equal or not, it compares string's location.

You can click [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) for more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
    webview.loadUrl(login_address);
    Log.d("FlagCheck", "this flag is  login_address");

}else{

    webview.loadUrl(home_address);
    Log.d("FlagCheck", "this flag is  home_address");
}
```

> USed this...

```
  finish();

 Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("flag", "add");
        startActivity(i);
```

> Instead of (Remove Finish to above)

```
   Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("flag", "add");
        startActivity(i);
       finish()
```

> You Have Value pass the add and or other than you send also like that

```
   if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
     Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("flag", "add");
        startActivity(i);
       finish()

      }
      else
     {

       Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("flag", "home");
        startActivity(i);
       finish()
     }
```